# PHP email Headers - delivery option

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I've added the following code to our PHP Mail app which sends out emails:

```
$email_header .= "Disposition-Notification-To: $from"; 
$email_header .= "X-Confirm-Reading-To: $from";
```

However, we are not receiving any 'Delivered' or 'Read' confirmations.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

H.

Comment: The recipient's mail client decides whether to send confirmations of read and receipt. Most (wisely) choose not to.

Comment: Send an email to yourself, then use your client to check the headers.  Do you see them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that you are not receiving any confirmations is that most people choose not to send read receipts. If you could, from your server, influence whether or not this happened, a spammer could easily identify active and inactive email addresses quite easily.

However, another reason why this might be failing, if sending read receipts is enabled, is that you need to include a new line at the end of every line:

```
$email_header .= "Disposition-Notification-To: $from\r\n"; 
$email_header .= "X-Confirm-Reading-To: $from\r\n";
```

Comment: Line breaks in email headers should be `\r\n`, not just `\n`.

Comment: @Synchro According to [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) you're absolutely right . I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe one header for getting read notifications was `Return-Receipt-To:`. Also, users usually have the option to ignore the "read receipt", and not send the e-mail back, if the header is not ignored completely by the client.

Comment: OP has the right header, per this RFC: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3798#section-2.1

Comment: Hmm, well, turns out that there is a non-standard by that name, which is supported by some systems.  Downvote removed.  Rats, it won't let me change my vote.  Sorry.

Comment: I edited the answer, so you should be allowed to change the vote

Comment: Done.  And it turns out that there are several other non-standard headers for read receipt requests:  `Read-Receipt-To`, `Return-Receipt-Requested`, `X-Confirm-Reading-To`, and `Generate-Delivery-Report`.

Answer (score -1):

(maybe not the answer to the question, but the probable answer to what you are trying to achieve is). Your method won't work most of the times as confirmations are usually disabled. Use a image tag to record the email reads in the email. It won't work if the loading of images is disabled.